# Versioning cross micro service dependencies

Tags: microservices

**Architecture overview**
Consider the following simplified microservice architecture:

- Service A - Portal
- Service B - API

Service A depends on Service B.

**Problem statement**
If I want to build a new backward-compatible feature in service A which requires changes to service B, then by definition of semantic versioning I'll have to create a new minor version for both services. However, service A requires the new minor version of service B to be deployed. How can I effectively manage this dependency? Do I need to create a new major version of service A to signal the changed dependency? I want to avoid that service A gets deployed while service B hasn't been deployed yet...

So basically; how should I version changes which are non-breaking (i.e. minor) in components itself, but will break the overall application if versions don't match?

Comment: Since this is a non-breaking change then you could handle the resolution manually by ensuring you deploy the changes to Service B before you ship the changes to Service A that expect new endpoints/features in B. However, it sounds like you're looking for a means of auto-resolving these dependency relationships more like a package manager does - is that correct?

Comment: @DavidT. that's indeed correct. We have several production environments with each its own separate pipeline. So it's not possible to manually deploy service B before service A is shipped to all environments. 
It's closer related to helm charts than to a package manager.

Comment: That's what I thought. I've been working on a deploy tool to solve that problem specifically (deploy-time dependency resolution for microservices) for the past year and it's being released this coming week. The platform would provision and broker connectivity between related services as needed with each deploy job based on a service manifest that looks a lot like a manifest for any other package manager. If you're interested in trying it out I can reply with the link in the next couple days.

Comment: @DavidT. Yes please, I'm very interested!

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Just released our beta this week, and I’d love for you to try it out and see if it fits what you were looking for: Architect.io

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to break the existing API contracts. Lets call your existing API (service B ) myapi/v1/products. You won't change anything in the existing API or this end point at all. You will create new version call it myapi/v2/products and deploy it. Its your choice where and how you host that end point. This end point has all the latest changes you want. Your portal is not affected yet.

Now you would deploy the portal and would use myapi/v1/ for features that require backward compatibility and myapi/v2/ for new features and this way you can manage API versioning without breaking features.

Hope that helps!

Comment: For minor changes, inplace using key-sentinels is often useful (eg. presence of a new field, which is so much easier with a DTO-structure). Still requires timed rollouts.